# Repository troubles - Help!

Tags: repositories

I tried to install a music player called Cantata, and it looks like it is no longer current, now every morning when doing its round of updates I get the message "The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/cantata/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default." 
What do I do? What is the command line to remove the repository? 
Thanks! Fred

Comment: [How to remove repositories in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used this link: https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-remove-delete-ppas-on-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint-elementary-os/

Method 3 worked fine for me.

All clear!